# repeat background-color under background-image

Tags: html, css

I currently have an image that is a specific height and width, how would I set a specific color to run endlessly under the image.

```
body {
    background-image: location;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

I'd like to background-color to be below the background-image and not all over the page but just under it.

### update

html has background-color: #red

body background-image: .png image & background-color: #fff;

I'd like the background-color to not overflow the html color which is the top and just overflow under the background-image from the body.

Comment: img { background-color: #FF0000; } ???

Comment: If it was that simple I wouldn't have to ask. If I were to do that, the background-color would be all over the page, I need it to be under the image, not all over the page.

Comment: if img { background-color: #FF0000; } makes your whole page (body) red, then your image is quite big... also your question needs some edit. your changing from talking about an image to an background-image.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
background:#ffffff url(ImageUrl) no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
background:red url(../img/s.jpg) no-repeat center top;
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/H6ffn/6/)

or

```
background-color: red;/*...background colour..*/
background-image: url(../img/s.jpg);/*...image source...*/
background-position: center top;/*...position of background image...*/
background-repeat: no-repeat;/*...it will avoid repetition of image..*/
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/H6ffn/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this one line code

```
body{
    background:#ffffff url('img_tree.png') no-repeat right top;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background_shorthand)